# Efficient Storage Strategies for Apriori Association Rules in Large Datasets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apriori

Is it practical to store Apriori association rules for large datasets, and what are recommended approaches for efficient storage considering the potentially extensive number of rules?

I have explored storing Apriori association rules using a relational database and serializing them in JSON format. However, I encountered challenges with the growing number of rules and the overall efficiency. I expected these approaches to provide a scalable solution for large datasets, but I am seeking advice on more effective strategies or alternative methods.